# Task.cs not Found

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal, mscorlib

We have developed a Windows Store App using Visual Studio 2017. We are using AAD to login to the app. Things are ok on the compile side and we are able to create a release package. The issue arises when we try to run the app that is generated. Once the app starts and user enters it credentials it tells the user that the credentials are not valid.

[image]

When we try to debug the issue we find out that the application throws a "Task.cs" not found exception. This error is only thrown if we check the ".Net Native Tool Chain" checkbox in the build options. If we do not check that box and create a package then the resulted app runs just fine. Now the file that the debugger complains about is part of mscorlib library and this library is added to the solution and is shown amongst the references. Scratching our heads as to how to get past this issue and get the thing working. Please refer the screenshot and the description of the error below.
[image]

```
Locating source for 'f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Threading\Tasks\Task.cs'. (No checksum.)
The file 'f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Threading\Tasks\Task.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Threading\Tasks\Task.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Threading\Tasks\Task.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\cvt\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\msclr\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\sys\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\thr\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\crt\src\x64\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\crt\src\arm\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\crt\src\concrt\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\crt\src\i386\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\crt\src\linkopts\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\crt\src\stl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\crt\src\vccorlib\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\crt\src\vcruntime\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\atlmfc\include\'...
Looking for source using source server...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Threading\Tasks\Task.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Threading\Tasks\Task.cs'.
```

As I mentioned earlier, this exception only gets thrown when we compile the solution with the "Compile with .Net Native tool chain" checkbox checked. We put a block to catch the message, the trace, the type of exception. The message and type we are getting are:

**The Message:**
Unresolved P/Invoke method 'InternetSetOption!wininet.dll' from this method. Please look for this method in build warnings for more details.

**Exception Type:**    System.TypeLoadException

Further analysis shows that the exception is being thrown by the following line in the Signout method:

```
authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
```

Below is the complete method

```
private void SignOut()
        {
            try
            {
                authContext.TokenCache.Clear();

                // Also clear cookies from the browser control.
                ClearCookies();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the exact `Type` and `StackTrace` of the exception?

Comment: @mjwills Done :)

Comment: That seems to be sayign that it can't find the source for "Task.cs" to show it to you in the debugger - it doesn't look like the original error...

Comment: @chris You are right. This is the error that we get when we run the debugger. Also the error only gets generated when we have the .Net Native Tool Chain checked. If we do not have that checkbox checked then all is fine, however then off course we will not be able to put the app on store without having that checkbox checked.

Comment: @MuhammadKhurramBhatti: My point is what you are showing isn't an error with your program, its an error you are having with visual studio's debugging. Its Visual studio that can't find task.cs, not your program. So what you need to do is find the *actual* error that is causing this. Using the call stack tab at the bottom of your screen will help find where your actual error is.

Comment: @mjwills I have added the code snippet of the last method that gets called. The issue only appears when "Compile with .Net Native tool chain" is checked. The code since it compiles and runs just fine if we create the package without checking this checkbox.

Comment: @chris I have also added the detail of the error that we are getting.

Comment: Do you really want to be catching all exceptions and returning null in that code? It seems to me that an inability to read the config file isn't a problem you just ignore and move on with... Perhaps you should put a breakpoint in that exception and find out what exception is being thrown there? Also I don't know what your last screenshot is but it appears to be a debug view of a Response object, not an exception. I do note though that in that response you are getting a 403 access denied which is probably not what you want either...

Comment: @chris apologies for posting the wrong screenshot. I have put the correct one now.

Comment: Given that your error message says "Your credentials did not work" and your last screenshot was of a Response object with a 403 response is there any reason you are not just looking at that part of the code and seeing what credentials it is sending or looking at the server to see why it returned a 403? Also why on earth is your error message "Credentials did not work or the service is down"? It seems like you should be able to tell the difference between the two.

Comment: @Chris my friend. As stated earlier, it was the wrong screenshot and was for another error we worked on previously. That issue has been resolved and is not related to this one.

Comment: OK. Well your new screenshot doesn't show an exception either which is why I went back and reread the question and realised that your stated error was it saying "Your credentials did not work" which is why I thought maybe you should be looking at that code. To be honest given how hard this is to get you to post actual details of the exception (or even evidence that an exception is being thrown) I am just voting to close this question. Until this question has the exact type of exception, the message of the exception and a stack trace there seems very little anybody can do to help.

Comment: @Chris quite understand your frustration. Problem is that we are not getting any info regarding type and message. I have shared all that we are being thrown at as Stack. Have added screenshot of Call Stack as well and the last method that is getting called in our code. I really am struggling as to what else can be shared at this point :(

Comment: OK. Lets go back to basics? How do you know you have an exception? I am struggling to see how you can know you have an exception but being unable to see it. Can you put a try/catch in your Login.OnNavigatedTo method to catch the exception and then either break in that or log it?

Comment: @Chris We added the tracing to the code as you suggested and now we know that the exception is being thrown by our SignOut method and when we try to explicitly clear the cache. I have added the message and the type to the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the issue was caused by the SignOut method that was being called as part of the Signin process. We commented out that method and were able to go past this issue. Thanks @Chris for the help.

Comment: Thought I did 